# How to request a channel's videos on ruby

Tags: ruby, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

im trying request a channel's videos for discord notification.

thats mean i request datas for per minute.

i just reach with search and that mean its cost 100

its just for my hobby and i dont want to pay for that.

have any idea how can i get last uploaded videos without search.

here my codes if u interest:

```
require "yt"
Yt.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'mykey'
end
channel1 = Yt::Channel.new id: 'UCQjhFO_CA5e1-Ymopbfmx5Q'
videos = channel1.videos
video2 = videos.where(id:' UCQjhFO_CA5e1-Ymopbfmx5Q').map(&:id)
puts video2
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

I solved with playlists.
firstly u should create a playlist and upload all videos on that playlist after that

u can use this codes :

```
Yt.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'Yourkey'
end

item = Yt::Playlist.new(id: 'PLj-AxDUBuKVyraMkOwGloWO_zcUB0XNH-').playlist_items.first
item1 = item.video_id
```

it spends 5 quotas per request.